# filtering algorithm trouble

Tags: java, arrays, filter

```
public static String filterPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {

    Character[] characters = new Character[phoneNumber.length()];
    if (characters.length > 9)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++)
        {
            if (characters[i] != ' ')
            {
                characters[i] = phoneNumber.charAt(i);
            } else
            {
                Log.d("asd", "wrroooonggggggggg");
            }
        }
    }
    return phoneNumber;
}
```

Im trying to filter empty chars in the number, but when 2 or more empty chars are found in the string, it removes only the first.

Comment: `algorythm makes criticall errors` please explain.

Comment: I think you want `i < characters.length`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you increase `i` in the for-loop and when you find a space you skip it. When you in the next loop set the number in `characters` you have skipped one entry. You must use two stepping variables, one for stepping `phoneNumber` and one for `characters`.

It looks like you want to return a filter phone number, but are returning the values that you sent in.

There is a search and replace method on String that you can use.

```
public static String filterPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
  return phoneNumber.replaceAll(" ","");
}
```

Here is how it is used: http://runnable.com/VUfHvPvHoEdLO3id/filterphonenumber-for-java

Comment: i can't imagine how it can be used

Comment: hey! nice to know about runnable.com. First time I see it. I'm up voting you for it :)

Comment: it didn't help. 1st space is removed, but 2nd one and others are'nt.

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
char[] characters = new char[phoneNumber.length()];
```

it works.

Comment: OMG it worked. New trouble is when 2 or more empty chars in string it removes only 1st.

Answer (score 0):

1. your characters array should be of the type `char[]`
2. characters array is never initialized, so `characters[i] != ' '` is always true (provided that you fix the array type, else should throw a `NullPointerException`)
3. you're assign `characters[i] = phoneNumber.charAt(i)` but you never read it afterwards.

If your goal is to remove spaces just do this:

```
public static String filterPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
    return phoneNumber.replaceAll(" ", "");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Working 100%

```
public static String filterPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {

    byte[] number = phoneNumber.getBytes();
    byte[] array = new byte[phoneNumber.length()];
    int count=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < number.length; i++){
        if (number[i] != ' '){
            array[count++] = number[i];
        }
    }
    return new String(array);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String res = filterPhoneNumber("   +28  23");
    System.out.println(res); //OUTPUT "+2823"
}
```

Comment: Why don't you propose him to use regex instead of an iteration

Comment: To understand what he is doing wrong.
Because the variable 'i' in his code, shouldn't increment at same stride that he increment the arg string. And it´s why I put the 'count' in my code

Comment: We should try to abide to the best practice rather than following someone. He is iterating over an array to replace space, we can use a regex.